# Find text on a webpage and write to file using Python 3 and BS4

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Running into issues when trying to use BS4 to scrape a site and provide back the results in a .txt file. Everything that I'm reading on BS4 does not cover how to pull data from the body only.

Example

```
`<html>
  <head></head>
  <body> ==$0
    <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
      "; A
      <B--need this data exported to my file>
       C
       D
       E
      <F--Also need this exported to my file>
   end`
```

- this format repeats over and over but the data structure is the same.

The code I have tested so far, still getting errors and haven't made it to the portion where I need to pull in the data from line B.

```
`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from bs4.element import comment

url = ('website')
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser"

for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract() 
text = soup.get_text()

lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())

body = soup.find(body)

body = soup.find(text="<word from site>")
outfile = open('file location','w')
outfile.write('body')`
```

Along with not having the knowledge of pulling the data from line B, Still learning Python, please forgive me if this makes sense!

Comment: Your html doesn't make sense. Can you provide the snippit of the actual html that youre trying to pull data from? Secondly, yes you can pull data from the `body` tag only. just use `body = soup.find('body')`

Comment: Can't share a snippit (sensitive data), the page is poorly coded hence it does not make much sense.  I added the suggested and was able to get the full list of data exported to my txt file, but this is still not giving me the exact word only that I'm looking for.  updating the post with the current script that is somewhat working..

Comment: It's still tough to do with the way you have the example since I have no idea what you're trying to do (saying "I want the data from line B" is still to broad/vague). What could really be useful is given the example you've given above, also give an example of what output are you wanting/expecting from the example above. That actually is all I'd need to know. So add to your question below, given the snippit of html, what should the output look like.